# How to redo a failed step in AWS emr

Tags: amazon-emr

My step in AWS emr is failing. How to redo only the step without creating another cluster using the UI . Couldn't find this info online.

Comment: If the EMR cluster is still running, you could just create a new step and configure it to do the same thing. You can create a new step via the UI for via Hadoop commands.

Comment: This question might be more suitable on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If the EMR is already terminated, is there a way to rerun the failed step? I use lambda to trigger EMR and step creation. If step fails, the EMR is terminated. I only need to run one step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option to 'clone' the step appears when you select the step. You will find this under the 'steps' tab.

[Example of steps tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cBFZ.png)

Comment: As mentioned before, only If EMR cluster is still running